# Where do pod labels get injected in prometheus-operator

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-operator

Where do pod / nodename labels get injected in prometheus-operator?
Is this configurable?

Comment: Do you mean "how would I make my own pod (not prometheus) scraped with the prometheus operator ?" ?

Comment: no, metrics exposed by each pod do not have pod label in them but prometheus-operator adds pod label to the metrics